# I am trying to implement video streaming in android using rtmp protocol with the help of flazr

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtmp

The documentation of flazr is really poor and am finding it really difficult to understand its implementation. I could get hold of only one such open source project on github called mconf-mobile [https://github.com/mconf/mconf-mobile](http://github.com/mconf/mconf-mobile). I would really appreciate if anybody could refer me to similar such projects or some detailed documentation regarding the implementation of flazr client in android such as implementing rtmp connection, handshaking, rendering, etc.

Comment: did u find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge go for the following url which helps to streaming video from android device

https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

Thanks